# node.js, mongoose - findOne({ _id: req.params.id }) doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am doing this exercice https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/6390246-passez-au-full-stack-avec-node-js-express-et-mongodb/exercises/3732

findOne() doesn't work:

```
app.get('/api/products/:id', (req, res, next) => {  
  console.log('Product.findOne({ id:'+req.params.id+'}) :' );
  Product.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })  
    .then(product  => { console.log("\nprod =\n"+json({product})); res.status(200).json({product})} ) 
    .catch(error   => { console.log('error here');                 res.status(404).json({ error })} );
});
```

My backend server shows in the terminal:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lFXd.png)

Two other routes work correctly:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIYk3.png)

The items are really in the database:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fPeW.png)

I've tried to replace findOne() by FindById().
I am a beginner and have tried hard to find a solution, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do somthing like this to make it work.

```
app.get('/api/products/:id', (req, res, next) => {  
  Product.findOne({_id: req.params.id })
  .then(product => {
     console.log(product) //To check the value we got from query
     res.status(200).json({product})
  })
.catch(err => {
   console.log(err)
})
});
```

Comment: Thank you very mush, it show the correct result in console.log(result) //To check the value we got from query, but the program still doesn't work

Comment: what is your expected output??

Comment: i have updated the ode once try with that

Comment: @ChessClub can you please upvote and mark it

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

You're trying to compare string with ObjectId

**Solution**

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
const id = ObjectId(req.params.id); // convert to ObjectId
Product.findOne({ _id: id })
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it change nothing. I do not see if I can attach asnap shop to my comments, but it gives just the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/getpost/:id', async (req, res) => {
  let gtpost = await post.findOne({_id: req.params.id})
  console.log(gtpost)  
})
```

After much trying this worked for me, hope it does for everyone.